# How can we find the develpoment language of a specific website?

Tags: web-development, language

first of all i m sorry if i post this thread on wrong website. Now my question is:

```
 is there any method/trick to find the programming (scripting) language of 
 a website on which that website is developed.
```

for eg: i want to know the development language of **https://mydeco.com/**

is above website is developed on **PHP**, **ASP.net**, **RUBY(ROR)** ,**PYTHON** OR any other language.

please suggest how to find??

Thanks for helping me always.

i found a website where its display header information

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2011 11:36:54 GMT 
Server: Apache 
Location: http://mydeco.com/ 
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Connection: close 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

does anybody now can tell me the web language??
Keshav

Comment: @Sinan that answer also dont have any proper answer

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to be 100% sure unless they tell you (and this site doesn't seem to do so). So send them an email and see what they say.

Answer (score 2):

**Mydeco appear to use Python and the [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) framework.**

To find out what technologies big commercial websites use, it's worth trying their [jobs page](http://mydeco.com/jobs/) to see what they ask for when hiring new recruits to their Web team.

In this case, they had a position for a Senior Front End Web Developer in [December 2008](http://web.archive.org/web/20081210042157/http://mydeco.com/jobs/) that makes reference to Django. Their current position for a Data Analyst also mentions Python. This would fall in line with their server architecture, which appears to be Apache under Linux on an Amazon instance [[source](http://uptime.netcraft.com/up/graph?site=mydeco.com)]. This is not necessarily conclusive, though, and you should simply email them as John suggests if you'd like to confirm it.

Update: mydeco.com is [featured on djangosites.](http://www.djangosites.org/s/mydeco-com/)

Answer (score 1):

try http://builtwith.com/ but it is hard to recognize technologies used and even impossible on some sites

Answer (score 0):

With some sites you can look at the extensions of the filenames, but they hide them quite well. One clue is some script in the home page which begins like this:

```
<% if (target == "share") { %>
```

That's ASP script.

However the server says it's Apache, so it's not clear what language is being used.

Comment: if it was asp or asp.net that script would run and executed on server and would not be rendered and seen in browser.